# How to identifiy this "2222 063 90025" vintage capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, electrolytic-capacitor, vacuum-tube, vintage

I am restoring an old stereo valve amp and would like to test (and replace if needed) some components.  I don't know the history of the amp, but it's made in New Zealand and looks to be from the 1960's or 70's, but I could be wrong.

There are a couple of capacitors that need identifying.  The first and larger one is clearly marked 50 \$\mu\$F, however, it has three legs.  What I would like to know about this capacitor is:

- Do the three legs signify a 2-in-1 capacitor?
- What does the product code of `2222 063 90025` signify (tried [here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/28394/prodcode.pdf), but no luck)?
- What do the triangle, square and circle symbols indicate?
- How do replace this capacitor?

Capactior product code:
[image: Capacitor product code]

Capacitor from below, with 3 pins:

[image: Capacitor from below]

Comment: It seems that contacts have those fancy symbols, I can see a square and circle, possibly the black wire is soldered to a contact with triangle marking.

Comment: The "black wire" is a tinned wire with a length of woven sleeving slipped over it - standard fare for the period

Comment: "Vintage"???  Why, I built several devices with such capacitors!

Comment: The product code is a "12NC" (12 number code), which is used by Philips and many of its (former) subsidiaries. But the encoding doesn't seem to match Philips numbering: they used 22 (in positions 1 and 2) for resistors, and 23 for capacitors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a three section electrolytic capacitor, with the three symbols indicating which pin is associated with each capacitor positive lead. 
The three capacitors share a common negative terminal (the can) which you will observe is grounded by virtue of being bolted to the chassis. I see soldered lugs on the can to reinforce that connection.

Commonly used as the power supply reservoir capacitor in a vacuum tube amplifier.

Note that one section has a lower rated voltage : you'll see it's connected to the others via a high-ish resistance, to provide a well filtered (quiet) supply to the sensitive preamp stages.

Circuitry will be easy to trace out and will look roughly as below...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhLWDv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you can't find a replacement, you can use three separete 50uF 450V capacitors. Bonus points for assembling them into a lookalike can...

(A bit more reading suggests this was a Philips part number)

Comment: Best answer, thanks for mentioning how to replace them, if needed.

Comment: Where did you get the values for R1, R2 and D1? The green resistor seems to be 10kohm in the picture.

Comment: I said "roughly" - the photo disappears when the schematic editor is up so I was working from memory.. Substitute your actual values and note I probably swapped Circle and Square sections. It's a good idea to insert a 40W bulb (incandescent) between D1 and capacitor when testing the amp ... those capacitors will leak a lot at first, and (hopefully) heal themselves in hours or days. Or if you have a 200-400V DC supply you can re-form them via high value resistors and watch the leakage current decline. Read about "reforming" old electrolytics...

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be what is known as a "Triple Section Electrolytic Capacitor" which seems to be a fairly apt name.

The three legs have symbol stamped into them which correspond to each of the three markings on the capacitor. The shell is presumably then connected as the common terminal.

Essentially it appears to be three capacitors wired up in a Wye configuration, each 50uF in capacitance. Two are rated for 400V, and the third rated for 350V. Although the third one having a different rating seems to be weird.

Comment: I was wrong about not likely to be a wye of course with common neutral, sorry about that - but their normal use isPSU decoupling and I associate wye with 3ph AC for some reason...

Answer (score 4):

It is a twist lock multi section capacitor.

Seldom designed into new equipment but pretty common in still functioning and restored valve (audio) gear.

You could try and see if your circuit could cope with one of the replacement types from [TEDSS](https://www.tedss.com/Capacitors/Browse/aluminum-electrolytic-large-can-twist-lock) or from [Amplified Parts](https://www.amplifiedparts.com/search/node/50uF?cats%5B0%5D=112), failing which you could insert 3 x [50uf 400V contemporary radial electrolytic capacitors](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors/58?k=&pkeyword=&pv2049=u47%C2%B5F&pv2049=u48%C2%B5F&pv2049=u50%C2%B5F&pv2049=u51%C2%B5F&pv2049=u53%C2%B5F&pv2049=u55%C2%B5F&pv2049=u56%C2%B5F&pv2049=u58%C2%B5F&pv2079=u400V&pv2079=u415V&pv2079=u420V&pv2079=u450V&pv2079=u475V&FV=ffe0003a&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) under the chassis or into the gutted old can.

The can will be the common negative terminal.